# Are there any other modifier keys on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, autohotkey

I'm trying to use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key as a modifier key on Windows. So far, the best approach I found is to map it to another key using AutoHotKeys. For example, I can map the <kbd>left Win</kbd> key to the <kbd>left Control</kbd> key and it works as expected.

To achieve my goal I'd need to map the Win key to another modifier key, one that is not any of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Is there such a thing? Even if I have to use the raw key code, that's fine.

Comment: My Dell keyboard only has a left Win key, but it does have separate left and right Alt keys, so if yours does too, you could use them as two different separate modifiers.

Comment: You could use the Alt-Menu key if you have one.

Comment: @martineau I thought of that, but IntelliJ, the main application I use, doesn't differentiate between left and right keys when setting up modifiers.

Comment: @davidpostill: I'm not looking for a key that I have but for a key I don't have, to map the Win key to it. I tried using the menu key, but it's not a modifier key, so alt+menu won't work either.

Comment: In that case, you should ask JetBrains to modify their IntelliJ IDE to allow differentiation of the two Alt keys.

Comment: Also, another approach might be to use what autohotkey calls a prefix modifier key. For example, I have one set up to type the fraction ½ which is triggered by first pressing the numeric `1` key and then, at the same time, the numeric `2` key. The ahk code is: `Numpad1 & Numpad2::Send, ½`

Comment: The Win key **is** a modifier key on Windows (= it modifies the function of other keys in key-combinations). Using Autohotkey you can extend its function as modifier key by creating new key-combinations.